# Enable server notifications for auto-renewable subscriptions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

As per [this](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev0067a330b) documentation

A server URL to receive update notifications (JSON object posts) for key subscription events. This is applicable only for apps containing auto-renewable subscriptions. It is recommended to use these notifications in conjunction with Receipt Validation to validate users' current subscription status and provide them with service

[image]

We have added the URL but while checking the server log the link is not pinged,
Q1 - Is there any additional setup I need to do to test it in the sandbox?
Q2 - Is it only work for real purchase made by the user on production?
Q3 - Should I need to push an update to app store to make the Subscription URL work?

Any suggestion will be helpfull

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Have you setup the required ATS protocols on your server? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW57

2) It looks like it works for both sandbox and production according to the possible responses from their documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW13

3) You shouldn't need to push an update to app store for it work.

Comment: Sir have you tested it?

Comment: It seems to work for us, but we have a large amount notifications arriving multiple times with 24 hours interval.

Comment: @silentser

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46218509/get-blank-response-subscription-status-url-iap-from-apple-server-status-update

Above is my question.

I set Subscription Status URL in my APP in iTunes account like https://www.xxxxxx.xx/iospushnotification.php

I also successfully tested nscurl --ats-diagnostics https://www.xxxxxx.xx/iospushnotification.php

I have set  Subscription Status URL, implement php code to get JSOB but I can not get response, I get response like [ ]  \nArray\n

Comment: @silentser

can you tell me is there any extra code we need on Server Side or any setting?
can you tell me is there any extra code we need on out App Side or any setting?

in Appside I set App Transport Security Settings -> Allow Arbitrary Loads = true

 plz help me

Comment: @silentser 
I tested all things in developer profile 
is it necessary to test in distribution profile?

Comment: @AnkurPatel Did you succeed? Did you tried with distribution profile ?

Comment: No I did not try. 
Did you try?
I will try with sandbox tester with distribution profile.